# how can i get list of created and deleted files on the server?

Tags: log-files, file-sharing, files

i have a image sharing website , users log and upload image 
last night i've lost about 30 newly-consecutive uploaded images ... i mean they have been uploaded ... apparently ... they are in the database but the actual image on the server is gone !

error log doesn't show anything ... so i thought my best option is to check list of created and deleted files ... if there is any !
is there a log file for created and deleted files on the server ? i'm using directadmin

Comment: How are these files uploaded and deleted?  HTTP?   FTP?  SCP?

Comment: @MadHatter HTTP

Comment: Check your http logs, then.  Try uploading and deleting one file, so you know what the log signature of the activities is (which will be specific to the code you are using), then look for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track changes in a filesystem using the `auditd(8)` capablilities:

A simple example:

```
# mkdir /root/test
# auditctl -w /root/test/ -p wa
# touch test/foo
# rm -f test/foo
```

The logs are kept in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and can be further analyzed:

```
# tail /var/log/audit/audit.log
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1372668317.891:159): auid=0 ses=6 subj=unconfined_u:system_r:insmod_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 op="add rule" key=(null) list=4 res=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372668344.279:160): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7fff4884994f a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=7fff48847900 items=2 ppid=3817 pid=5859 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=6 tty=pts3 comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:insmod_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=CWD msg=audit(1372668344.279:160):  cwd="/root"
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668344.279:160): item=0 name="test/" inode=4271 dev=fe:01 mode=040700 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668344.279:160): item=1 name="test/foo" inode=4723 dev=fe:01 mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372668371.491:161): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=15850c0 a2=0 a3=7fff0e0cd790 items=2 ppid=3817 pid=5866 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=6 tty=pts3 comm="rm" exe="/bin/rm" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:insmod_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=CWD msg=audit(1372668371.491:161):  cwd="/root"
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668371.491:161): item=0 name="test/" inode=4271 dev=fe:01 mode=040700 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668371.491:161): item=1 name="test/foo" inode=4723 dev=fe:01 mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0

# ausearch -m SYSCALL -ts recent
----
time->Mon Jul  1 10:45:44 2013
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668344.279:160): item=1 name="test/foo" inode=4723 dev=fe:01 mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668344.279:160): item=0 name="test/" inode=4271 dev=fe:01 mode=040700 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=CWD msg=audit(1372668344.279:160):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372668344.279:160): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7fff4884994f a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=7fff48847900 items=2 ppid=3817 pid=5859 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=6 tty=pts3 comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:insmod_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
----
time->Mon Jul  1 10:46:11 2013
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668371.491:161): item=1 name="test/foo" inode=4723 dev=fe:01 mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=PATH msg=audit(1372668371.491:161): item=0 name="test/" inode=4271 dev=fe:01 mode=040700 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
type=CWD msg=audit(1372668371.491:161):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1372668371.491:161): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=15850c0 a2=0 a3=7fff0e0cd790 items=2 ppid=3817 pid=5866 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=6 tty=pts3 comm="rm" exe="/bin/rm" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:insmod_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't effectively get such a list.  You can use `inotifywatch` if you are using linux and your linux distribution supports it to see files being created and deleted in a directory in realtime, but not historically (such logs are not kept).

You should consider checking your filesystem for consistency if files are being lost.  In ext2 and some other filesystems they will appear in the `lost+found` folder in the partition root, but the exact way to identify this depends on your filesystem.

Check also whether you have a periodic job running which might delete them for some reason (such as by restoring a directory from a backup).